# Mobile responsive design or at least increasing font size?

Tags: javascript, responsive, ag-grid

I get that this is commercial now for support but hoping that someone can point me in the right direction

I've looked here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-responsiveness/ and here: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-customise-theme ... so I'm close ... but I need to put it all together

My main goal is to do a media query (or onGridSizeChanged) to ...

a.  mainly set a different font size
b.  possibly ditch some columns

... for a mobile device (or desktop if mobile first)

Anything else I need to put this together?

Finally, it seems I won't be able to do a card (stacked) layout, right?

Comment: You can write your overriding css file with media queries and you should be able to achieve card stack view, I guess. At the end of the day ag-grid is rendered in html and you need to override appropriate classes?

Comment: Thanks @koolhuman ... I'm moreso trying to find the "official" way to make size changes but I can't find it in the ag-grid documentation.  They talk about how to do things the wrong way so I'm trying to do it right.

Comment: Going to remove my answer. I must have misread your issue and not realizing that you wanted media query issues resolved.

Comment: It still may help someone ... but unless I totally am missing it I don’t think a preprocessed solution lets a browser responsively react and adjust the grid font to viewport size